# How to join Pandas dataframes, but only use the rows in a right dataframe just once for every row in the left dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

So I have two dataframes like this:

df1=

```
ID      Amount    Reference
2        15.34    ABC
2        15.34    DEF
```

df2=

```
ID_r      Amount_r    Reference_r
2        15.34    123
2        15.34    123
2        15.34    345
3        15.34    456
```

I want to join DF1 with any 2 values on df2 so long as the ID and amount match

So I want my output to be something along the lines of

```
ID      Amount    Reference   ID_r      Amount_r    Reference_r
2        15.34    ABC         2          15.34          123
2        15.34    DEF         2          15.34          345
```

However doing a regular left join like pd.merge(df1,df2,how=left) provides an output of 6 rows with every combination possible. I just need to join df1 on 2 unique rows of data in df2.

To expand on the example, let's say I have a dataframe df3

df3=

```
ID_r      Amount_r    Reference_r
2        15.34        789
```

I want to merge df1 with df3 and since there is only one row of data available in df3, I want the output of the merge to be

```
ID      Amount    Reference   ID_r      Amount_r    Reference_r
2        15.34    ABC         2          15.34          789
2        15.34    DEF         N/A        N/A            N/A
```

Since I am merging only on unique right rows, there is no second row of data on df3 to merge with df1. However, doing a regular left join on ID and amount would give 2 rows of data with df3's row used twice on df1.

Output of left joining df1 and df3 on ID and amount (not wanted)

```
ID      Amount    Reference   ID_r      Amount_r    Reference_r
2        15.34    ABC         2          15.34          789
2        15.34    DEF         2          15.34          789
```

This is basically so I can confirm there's a unique row of data in df2/df3 for every row of data in df1, with the same ID and amount, however I can't use the same row of data in df2 twice.

Comment: something like: `df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates())` ?

Comment: you need to remove the duplicate keys in df2 first

Comment: I believe dropping duplicates wouldn't solve the issue of merging df1's row with a unique df2 value, a left join would still merge both of df2's values with df1 so I would have 4 rows of data instead of 2.

Comment: As far I am understanding your problem, you can do join using multiple columns. Use 'on' clause and pass the list of columns you want to use as base. For e.g. pd.merge(left=, right=, on=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])